# Is there a .net equivalent of a Java initialization Servlet?

Tags: .net, wcf, servicebehavior, endpointbehavior

Is there a .net equivalent of a Java initialization Servlet?

While we're at it, the equivalent of a filter?

And finally if said thing exists (filters) can these run before/after a request is made to a WCF service?

Comment: Are you specifically using WCF?  If so, are you using it in or out of IIS?

Comment: For that matter, what is a Java filter exactly?

Comment: @casperOne: Using WCF for web services (server web services) in IIS. You can look at a filter as an "interceptor". Once a request is made to a web-resource a filter can pre-process (or post-process, or both) the request (or response). One use for filters (in bound) might be logging, a few uses of outbound filters include adding headers (think no-cache), and compressing responses (gzip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[While you can use the OnStart event of HttpApplication to intercept when the service starts as well as IHttpModule for intercepting requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136194/is-there-a-net-equivalent-of-a-java-initialization-servlet/4136258#4136258), it is ***not*** the correct way to perform these interceptions in WCF.

The only reason that recommendation works is because you are being hosted in IIS and using IIS-specific hooks.  However, WCF services can be hosted anywhere, and you might find that you move your service to a service process, as well as change the bindings (you might use net-tcp instead of http, for example, in which case, how would you read the content coming in through an IHttpModule implementation?  You couldn't) which would cause these hooks to break.

That said, ideally you would perform any kind of initialization before you create your [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) instance.  However, since you don't have access to the ServiceHost instance in WCF in IIS, you will have to implement a custom [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx) and [specify that factory in your svc file (see the section titled Using a Custom ServiceHost in IIS or WAS).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx)  Taking this approach will make it portable.

As for intercepting calls, you can do that on the client and on the service side.  On the client side, you would implement [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) and on the server side you want [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) (I assume you want the latter).

In order to "inject" this inspector on the service side, you would have to use an endpoint behavior (which would apply to a specific endpoint on the service, an implementation of [IEndpointBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx)) or a service behavior (which applies to all endpoints on the service, through an implementation of the [IServiceBehavior interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx)).

It is through those implementations that you would look at the [ServiceEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.aspx) (for endpoint behaviors) or [ServiceDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedescription.aspx) class to apply the implementation of your inspector, or any one of the other hooks available in WCF.

You can read [Paolo Pialorsi's "Writing a WCF Message Inspector"](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) for a full walkthrough of how to pull this all together and give you insight into custom behaviors in WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know the java frameworks, but from the sounds of it you might be looking for the Global.asax [`HttpApplication.Application_OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28VS.71%29.aspx) event for initialization.

And filters?  Try [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, but -1 because both of those recommendations, while they will work in IIS, are not portable at all, and will present major problems if the service is to be transported outside of an IIS host. There are IIS-agnostic ways of doing this in WCF.

Comment: I don't know that the down vote is necessary, but good point.